# NPM throw error when i'm trying to install new package

Tags: git, npm

Hello I have following issue, when I try to install any node package in my react app I receive this error:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\earth\Desktop\Project\DAPP\client\node_modules\websocket
npm ERR! code EISGIT
npm ERR! git C:\Users\earth\Desktop\Project\DAPP\client\node_modules\websocket: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git     C:\Users\earth\Desktop\Project\DAPP\client\node_modules\websocket
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\earth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-01T19_35_16_846Z-debug.log
```

And im not able to install any packages, how can I fix it?

Comment: Please post an example npm command you are using to install a package with.

Comment: npm i react-responsive-modal --save, in my client folder

Comment: Try deleting node_modules folder and running npm i again. Make sure you are in the folder with your package.json when running the command.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I just solved it. It always seems to work like this: When searching for a solution for hours, you find nothing. But once you post on StackOverflow, you find a solution by yourself right after.

Anyway, the problem was there was a .git folder in 
`C:\Users\earth\Desktop\Project\DAPP\client\node_modules\websocket`. I deleted it manually and now installing the package works.

Comment: "But once you post on StackOverflow, you find a solution by yourself right after." -- it's a flavor of duck debugging

Answer (score 0):

I tried three times delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` but unsuccessfully. I tried deleting by commando line and manually and didn't work.

**The only way that I found to make it works was by using `yarn install`** instead of `npm install` after deleting the  `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. If you don't have yarn or don't know what's this you could look [Yarn Package Website](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#windows-stable)